# Netsuite - Exported CSV file contains "&amp;" instead of "&"

Tags: mapreduce, export-to-csv, netsuite, suitescript2.0, saved-searches

I have exported CSV file in NetSuite by Map/Reduce script and saved that file in file cabinet folder. But in the CSV file `&` is replaced with `&amp;`.
I tried to resolve it with replace method but it is not working.
I tried different encoding other than UTF8, but that is also not working.
Please do tell how this will be resolved.

Comment: How did you try to replace in CSV?  Using a text editor works okay for me.

Comment: I have created a script and I am trying to replace using that script.

Comment: Then you may want to post the script here so that the community can provide suggestions.